# Want to know about database design and best practice of table relationship

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, database-design, code-first

At first I want to give an example. Here I will use *code first* approach to make database tables and their relationship. Please look at the `class` below. (`C#`)

```
public class Blog 
{ 
  public int BlogId { get; set; } 
  public string Name { get; set; } 

  public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; } 
} 

  public class Post 
{ 
  public int PostId { get; set; } 
  public string Title { get; set; } 
  public string Content { get; set; } 

  public int BlogId { get; set; } 
  public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; } 
}
```

You’ll notice that I'm making the two navigation properties (Blog.Posts and Post.Blog) virtual. This enables the Lazy Loading feature of Entity Framework. Lazy Loading means that the contents of these properties will be automatically loaded from the database when you try to access them.

**Now Here is my question.**

I want to make a Database as like below. The table names will be:

`tblCompany`

`tblSite`  `// Site will be create under Company (A Company will have one or more Sites).`

`tblLine`  `// Line will be create under Site (A Site will have one or more Lines).`

`tblMachine`  `// Machine will be create under Line (A Line will have one or more Machines).`

> > So I will create,
> >
> > *Company* table and it will have a `Company_Id`.

.

> > Then I will create,
> >
> > *Site* table and this table will have `Site_Id` and `Company_Id` for making relationship between *Site* Table and *Company* Table

.

> > After that when I create *Line* Table should I user both `Company_Id`
> >      and `Site_Id`?

I know I can use only `Site_Id` and by query I can get the *Site* which *Company* belongs to. But what is the best practice? Should I use every Table's `Id` or I just use Previous Table's `Id`?

And also provide the `class` if anyone can.

Answer (score 1):

No, you shouldn't have every table in a hierarchy having every ID from every table above it, because we can use joins to link the tables together in the entire hierarchy chain.

There may be a very limited number of situations where it's specifically advantageous to have a lower level table have the ID of one much further above it, embedded within it but it's typically a developer convenience, when they think "I can't be bothered joining these 27 tables together every time I want to know which machine belongs to which company. I'll just have a companyid in the machine table and I promise I'll keep it updated by some complicated mechanism"..

.. Don't do it.. when you sell a site to another company you have to remember to transfer all the machines to them too, not just by selling the site, but visiting every machine and updating its company ID, otherwise the hierarchy gets messed up

What's the alternative, if your front end app will be querying a million times a second which machines belong to which company, and you don't want the database to have to join 27 tables together, a million times a second, to find this out? Caching; a separate system where you maintain a transient list of machines and companies. Every time you sell something or make a transfer, you invalidate the cache when you update the part of the database hierarchy. Upon next query, the cache misses and shall be rebuilt with the new info. The database only occasionally has to join 27 tables

This is starting to head into an opinion piece, and hence heading out of scope of a SO question/answer, but if you come up against specific problems as you implement your system, feel free to post them up

Ps: don't prefix your tables with tbl; it's obvious what they are. The days of having to give everything a name that included the type of thing it was have thankfully long gone

Comment: I think so :) . Thanks a lot for your answer bro. Come to know some useful things :) .